# The direct sum of injective modules need not be injective

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, nonnoetherian, injective-modules

The Bass-Papp Theorem asserts that a commutative ring $R$ is Noetherian iff every direct sum of injective $R$-modules is injective. Thus every non-Noetherian ring carries a counterexample.

If
$$
I_1 ⊊I_2⊊\cdots⊊I_n⊊\cdots
$$
is an infinite properly ascending chain of ideals of $R$, then for all $n$ let $E_n=E(R/I_n)$ be an injective envelope of $R/I_n$, and let $E=\bigoplus_{n\ge 1} E_n$. Then $E$ is a direct sum of injective modules and $E$ is not itself injective.
How to prove that $E$ itself is not injective?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard proof that I am aware of is actually explicit in this regard.

As you note, assume that $I_1\subsetneq I_2\subsetneq\cdots$ is an infinite ascending chain of ideals of $R$, let $E(R/I_n)$ be the injective envelope of $R/I_n$ for each $n$, and let $$E=\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}E(R/I_n)$$
be the their direct sum.

Let $I=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} I_n$.

For each $n$, let $f_n$ be the composition of the embedding $I\hookrightarrow R$ with the canonical map $R\to E(R/I_n)$ (map to the quotient, then embed into the envelope).

Since we have a map from $I$ to each $E(R/I_n)$, we obtain a map $f\colon I\to \mathop{\prod}\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}E(R/I_n)$ by the universal property of the product. In fact, the image of $f$ lies in the direct sum, since for every $x\in I$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in I_m$ for all $m\geq n$, hence the image of $x$ is $0$ in $R/I_n$.  So we have a map $I\to E$.

I claim that $f$ does not extend to a module homomorphism $\overline{f}\colon R\to E$ (which it would necessarily do if $E$ were injective). Assume to the contrary that we have an extension $\overline{f}\colon R\to E$. Being a module homomorphism with domain the free module of rank $1$, it is completely determined by $\overline{f}(1)$, and so it has the form $\overline{f}(x) = xe$ for all $x\in R$, where $e=\overline{f}(1)\in E$.

Now, let $n_0$ be a positive integer such that the $m$th component of $e$ is $0$ for all $m\geq n_0$. Let $x\in I_{n_0}\setminus I_{n_0-1}$. When we map $x$ to $R/I_{n_0}$, we obtain a nonzero element; hence the $n_0$th component of $f(x)$ must be nonzero (since $R/I_{n_0})$ embeds into $E(R/I_{n_0})$). But $f(x) = \overline{f}(x) = xe$, and the $n_0$th component of $e$ is $0$, hence so is that of $f(x)$, a contradiction.

The contradiction arises from the assumption that  we can extend the map $f\colon I\to E$ to a module homomorphism $R\to E$. Hence no such extension exists, so $E$ is not injective.

Comment: If I understand correctly, we do not need $E(R/I_n)$ to be an injective envelope, just being an injective module such that $R/I_n$ embed in it is sufficient, right? (In hindsight, it should be sufficient because we can embed the envelope into any such module, but this has the small advantage that one need not know about injective envelopes.)